# How to construct python post request with header and body

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I am completely new to Python. 
I need to post an authentication request to a website using header and body details.
I have posted the code below that I have so far. When I run it, I get syntax error on this line:

```
req.add_header('API-KEY': 'my_api_key', 'ACCOUNT-ID': 'my_account_id', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'VERSION': '2')
```

Can you please review and let me know where I've gone wrong?

```
import urllib.request
import json

body = {'identifier': 'my_id', 'password': 'my_encrypted_pwd', 'encryptedPassword': true}

url = 'https://mywebsite.com/gateway/deal/session'
req = urllib.request.Request(url)
req.add_header('API-KEY': 'my_api_key', 'ACCOUNT-ID': 'my_account_id', 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8', 'VERSION': '2')
jsondata = json.dumps(body)
jsondataasbytes = jsondata.encode('UTF-8')
req.add_header('Content-Length', len(jsondataasbytes))
print (jsondataasbytes)
response = urllib.request.urlopen(req, jsondataasbytes)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you should use the `requests` module, as it's faster and simply better than `urllib.request`:

```
response = requests.put(
        url,
        body, headers={'API-KEY': 'my_api_key',
                       'ACCOUNT-ID': 'my_account_id',
                       'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
                       'VERSION': '2'
              }
        )
```

Now you can parse the `response` you get as usual.